# Where to add track_changes option in migrate_d2d class

Tags: migrations

I have an ongoing migrate_d2d migration where I will need to be able to
detect changes on a node by node basis, and I would really like to be able to
use the functionality in the [Hash source rows to detect changes](http://drupal.org/node/1835822) feature to
do that.  However, I can't find where to add that option so that the hashes
are generated. I've tried this is my class (that overrides
DrupalNode6Migration):

```
$this->sourceOptions['track_changes'] = TRUE;
```

but the option isn't added and used. According to [this referenced post on this feature](http://timonweb.com/using-hash-value-trackchanges-to-detect-source-data-changes-in-migrate-for-drupal-7), I should add it in my source constructor, but that
part is handled by migrate_d2d in the abstract DrupalMigration class. Do I
need to go down to that level to create my class just to access this
property, or is there a way I can add it from my class that overrides
Drupal6NodeMigration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to synchronize sites.
http://timonweb.com/using-hash-value-trackchanges-to-detect-source-data-changes-in-migrate-for-drupal-7 
If you follow on this example you have mentioned above, Filter nodes by the update time these are changed after you deployed at last. You use MigrateSourceSQL. So you able modify a query.

If you want to synchronize sites, use the module: services or feeds.

Comment: No, I don't want to synchronize sites; I just want to regularly import a specific node type from one site to other. I'm very familiar with feeds, as I've been [using Feeds for the same thing](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/handling-custom-parsing-and-importing-with-feeds/89179#89179) on another site. In this case I was having issues with Feeds, so I wanted to try Migrate, as I've also used Migrate in the past for continuous migration of content, not just the initial migration.

Comment: So while migration process save the date of your last migration for an example into the system variable ym_last_migrtion_date. At the next migration you modify the SQL source query. Add  filter by date.

Comment: But why go through all that work when I can use the hash that Migrate already creates?